# Error When Ajax sending two Request to Wicket Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wicket-6

I am posting data to the wicket server via ajax when user click.to make the state ,retrieve the data when page loading ,via ajax GET, if only one request is sending then its working fine ,but in second request following error has thrown.
    org.apache.wicket.core.request.mapper.StalePageException
 How can I send the data to the server via ajax and later load the panel
  with the submitted data when user load it.

Code :Java Script
    Sending data to the server

```
function submitdata() {
    $.ajax({
        url : $('#mark').attr('json:callback.url1'),
        type : 'post',
        cache : false,
           data : ko.toJSON(familyModel),
           ntentType : 'application/json',
        dataType : 'json',
        complete : function() {
            } ,
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
                    console.log(xhr);
                    alert(status);
                    alert(error);
                 } 

            });}

        }

Page Load
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                url : $('#mark').attr('json:callback.url'),
                    type : 'GET',
                    cache : false,
                    contentType : 'application/json',
                    success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                              var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
                         // ko.mapping.fromJS(data, familyModel);
                /  ko.applyBindings(familyModel); 

                             // familyModel=new FamilyModel();
                              ko.applyBindings(familyModel); 

                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error){
                        console.log(xhr);
                        alert(status);
                        alert(error);
                     }
                }); 
                }

public class AbstractJSONBehavior extends AbstractAjaxBehavior {
public void onRequest() {


        RequestCycle requestCycle = RequestCycle.get();

        readRequestData(requestCycle);
        sendResponse(requestCycle);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using plain jQuery APIs and Wicket believes that the requests are non-Ajax, so it increments the `Page#renderCount` counter to prevent using page with stale information. 
If you use `Wicket.Ajax.post({...})` then Wicket will figure this out automatically.
So you can either use `Wicket.Ajax.post()` or pass either the request parameters or headers from https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/wicket-request/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/request/http/WebRequest.java#L40-L48 with value `true` to the jQuery#ajax().

Comment: Thanks martin, could you please provide an simple example to my code .

Comment: specilly "pass either the request parameters or headers from https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/wicket-request/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/request/http/WebRequest.java#L40-L48 "

Comment: Modify jQuery#Ajax with                                                                 headers: { 'Wicket-Ajax': true, 'Wicket-Ajax-BaseURL':$('#mark').attr('json:callback.url')} but still the exception is there